# SQL update row in view base tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a view that does a union between two tables in SQL Server. I am using a INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger to update the base tables. I have written this code to update Column1 on a specific row in the base tables, but I get an error:

```
IF UPDATE(Column1)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE BaseTable
        SET Column1 = I.Column1
        FROM inserted I INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Table2) AS BaseTable
        ON I.UniqueID = BaseTable.UniqueID
        WHERE BaseTable.UniqueID = I.UniqueID

    END

ERROR: Derived table 'Base' is not updatable because a column of the derived table is derived or constant.
```

Comment: Is `UniqueID` REALLY unique between the 2 tables. Not just "is unique now with the current data" but guaranteed to be unique? If they are identity columns, then you have taken a path to madness.

Comment: Those are generated unique strings unique across the whole database.

Comment: You may want to look at [Partitioned Views](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/09/partitioned-views-guide/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is actually pretty clear.  One of the requirements for a view/subquery/CTE to be updatable is that each column can be matched to a single column in a single table.  That is what the error message is trying to tell you.

You have to update the tables separately:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET Column1 = I.Column1
    FROM inserted I INNER JOIN
         Table1 t1
         ON I.UniqueID = t1.UniqueID;

UPDATE t2
    SET Column1 = I.Column1
    FROM inserted I INNER JOIN
         Table2 t2
         ON I.UniqueID = t2.UniqueID;
```

SQL Server only allows an `UPDATE` statement to update one table.

Comment: In my situation, I don't need to update both tables, but one OR the other, based on which table contains the row with the specified UniqueID. I would need to find the row on one of the two tables with the UniqueID column the same as the UniqueID column of the updated row. After finding which table the updated row is from, UPDATE only needs to run once against that table. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @AwiringCameron . . . So what?  (1) Only rows with matching ids will be updated; if none match a particular table, then no rows in that table are updated.  (2) `inserted` can contain multiple rows so it might have rows in both tables.

Comment: I didn't realize your solution does all these things. It looked to me like rows would get updated in both tables matching or not. Thanks for the help, I'm new to SQL...clearly!